# How to update 'pgrep' in macOS to get around a known 'pgrep -d' issue

Tags: macos, command-line, gnu

In the version of `pgrep` ( February 11, 2010 ) that is installed in macOS Catalina there is a bug when setting a delimiter. The delimiter should only be printed between each process ID but it's also being printed as a line terminator.

This is documented here in [the FreeBSD Bugzilla bug number 203744](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203744).

Is there a way to download an updated version of pgrep for macOS?

I also could not get the version of pgrep on my machine. Using `pgrep -V` results in an error. Using `what` gives me this:

```
what /usr/bin/pgrep
/usr/bin/pgrep
    PROGRAM:pkill  PROJECT:adv_cmds-174.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can. Just install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)!

Homebrew is a macOS package manager similar to `yum` in RedHat/CentOS Linux and `apt-get` in Debian/Ubuntu. It allows you to easily install packages that can supersede macOS built-in BSD (Darwin) commands and packages.

The first step to do this is to install Homebrew on your system like this; just open up a terminal and run the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Once Homebrew is installed on your system then install the [`protocol`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libsignal-protocol-c#default) package like this:

```
brew install proctools
```

And when that’s done, you can run your `prgrep` command and the version should be a more modern version that

Comment: I should have done `brew search --desc pgrep` instead of `brew search pgrep`

Comment: @John All fair. But what I did was do a Google search for `hombrew pgrep` and it was the top result.